# AJAX call issue in server side pagination in jqgrid

Tags: jsp, pagination, jqgrid

I am trying to implement server side pagination (no client side pagination) in jqgrid but not able to understand how to make ajax call on previous and next button click. I have more than one jqgrid in a single jsp.

My code is:

```js
 jq("#next_pager").click(function () {
             start =  start+ pageLimit;
             gridData = nextSubset(mydata, start, pageLimit);
             if(gridData.length > 0){
                 jq('#next_pager').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                 jq('#list').jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: gridData}).trigger('reloadGrid');
             }else{
                 start = 0;
                 jq('#next_pager').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
             }
         });
         jq("#prev_pager").click(function (){

             if(start > pageLimit){
                 start =  start - pageLimit;
             }else{
                 start = 0;
             }

             gridData = preSubset(mydata, start, pageLimit);
             
             jq('#prev_pager').removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
             jq('#list').jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: gridData}).trigger('reloadGrid');
             
         }); 

     function nextSubset(mydata, start, pageLimit){
         var subsetData = [];

         for(var index = start; index < start + pageLimit; index++){
                 subsetData.push(mydata[index]);
         }
         return subsetData;
     }

     function preSubset(mydata, start, pageLimit){
         var subsetData = [];

         for(var index = start - pageLimit; index < start; index++){
                 subsetData.push(mydata[index]);
         }
         return subsetData;
     }
     
     
function fetchPendingData() {
   var pendingParams = {};
   pendingParams.urlPath = 'path to backend controller';
   pendingParams.requestType = 'GET';
   pendingParams.data = null;
   pendingParams.callBackFunc = fetchPendingDataSuccess;
   verificationHandler.InitConfig(pendingParams.urlPath,
     pendingParams.requestType, pendingParams.callBackFunc, pendingParams.data,null,pendingParams.token,pendingParams.header);
   verificationHandler.MakeAjaxCall();
  }

  //Ajax success for Pending data for registration tab
     function fetchPendingDataSuccess(response) {
         pendingData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
         jq("#pendingListTable").jqGrid('clearGridData');
         for (var index = 0; index < pendingData.length; index++) {
             reformatePendingDataJson(index);
            // var gridData = nextSubset(mydata, start, pageLimit);
             loadPendingGridData(index + 1, pendingData[index]);
         }
     }
```

```html
<div class="tabs standard">
 <ul class="tab-links">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"
    id="VerificationTab" aria-expanded="false">Reporting Entity</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"
    id="profileEntityChangeVerificationTab" aria-expanded="true">Reporting Entity Profile Change</a></li>
 </ul>
   <div class="tab-content">
   <div id="tab1" class="tab active"
         aria-labelledby="VerificationTab">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
     <li role="presentation" class="active"><a
           href="#pendingUserList" id="pendingUserTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="pendingUser"
           aria-expanded="false">Pending</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="reportUploadTabsContent">
     <form class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel"
           id="pendingUserList" aria-labelledby="pendingUserTab" method="post">

    <table id="pendingListTable"
       class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    </table>
    <div id="pendingPjmap"></div>
    </form>
 </div>
</div>  
<div id="tab2" class="tab fade" aria-labelledby="profileEntityChangeVerificationTab">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills">
   <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#pendingUserProfile" id="pendingUserProfilelink"
 role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="pendingUserProfile" aria-expanded="false">Pending</a></li>
  </ul>
 <div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="pendingUserProfile">
      <table id="REPendingTable" width="100%" border="1">
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

How to make ajax call on previous and next button and how to load the same in jqgrid?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It looks like you are attaching events OK. Do these fire when you click on previous/next? Have you got any code to do an AJAX operation at this point? Presumably that would be standard jQuery code?